# What is more efficient in Javascript : while or for statements?

Tags: javascript, performance

I recently got the opportunity to do looping in javascript and I was rather confused whether to use for loop or while statement.

```
 var i = foo.length;
 while(i--){

 }
```

or

```
 for(var i=0 ;i<=foo.length;i++){

 }
```

I want to know from javascript guys which one is more effecient to use and under what circumstances should we use them accordingly. Is it same reason as in java or someting different.

Comment: I don't know that one would be more efficient than the other since each involves the same number of assignments and comparisons. For readability I would go with the 'for' loop, but that's a personal preference.

Comment: You can try it yourself at http://jsperf.com/for-vs-while-loop-iterating.

Comment: It's not a matter of efficiency, it's a matter of preference and readability. There's no practical difference as @pimvdb's test shows.

Comment: @pimvdb, thanks for the benchmark :) (fwiw, `for` is ~16% faster than `while` with Firefox 5 on my machine.)

Comment: http://jsben.ch/#/BQhED

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In theory the `while` loop is quicker because the `for` loop looks up the `length` attribute of `foo` every time though the loop, but in real-world use it's going to make an immeasurably small difference.

Comment: this is true for this particular example, where the statements are doing different things, for(i = foo.length; i > 0; i--) wouldn't lookup the length attribute of foo on every iteration but that's a O(1) operation anyway

Answer (score 8):

In some browsers some ways of looping are faster - for example, in Chrome, the `for` loop is more than twice as fast, but there is no consistent winner across all browsers. If you find a trick to make it really fast in one browser, you will be punished for it in another browser.

Actual performance test in different browsers: http://jsperf.com/for-or-while

You should use the type of loop that makes sense for the situation. In many cases what you do inside the loop takes a lot longer than the loop itself.

Answer (score 5):

For-loops are syntactic sugar for while loops. They should be exactly the same.

Your two loops, however, are semantically different. One counts to zero, while the other counts to a property of an object, which is bound to be slower, though only slightly so. It would be more meaningful to compare the above while-loop with the following for-loop:

```
for (var i = foo.length; i--;) { }
```

Answer (score 5):

Actually it has no significant difference which loop you use. every book I've read says so. there may be a difference in your example because you're using decremental looping in your while loop. it tends to be faster because the only one condition is evaluated.

e.g `while(i<100)` is slower than `while(i--)`

for your for loop you can store the length before the loop and work on that value instead of retrieving it every time. it will also give you some performance optimization.

```
var fooLength = foo.length;
 for(var i=0 ;i<= fooLength;i++){

 }
```

Comment: You could even do it in the first part of for(). for( var i = 0, arrLength = arr.length; i < arrLength; i++ )

Answer (score 5):

here's a good test of different loops in terms of performance: http://jsben.ch/#/BQhED

Answer (score 0):

There is not much difference in their "efficiency" or performance, use whichever makes the logic of your program more understandable on a case-by-case basis.