# What is the fastest way to click an element a million times

Tags: javascript

I'm doing this fun coding challenge that I found at a meetup (doyouevendev.org)

What is the fastest way to generate a million clicks on an element? The coding challenge seems to be centered around the inspector, which I'm finding worthwhile.

My code (that I'm executing in Chrome command line):

```
var item = document.getElementsByClassName("clicky-button pulse");
var item = item[0];
count = 0;
(function clickIt() {
    count += 1
    setInterval(function changeClicks() {
        item.click();
    }, 1);
    if (count <= 50) {
        clickIt();
    };
})();
```

I suspect there's a better way. It actually seems to be slowing down.

Comment: How about to split it into few threads?

Comment: "What is the fastest way to click an element a million times" - get a LOT of interns :)

Comment: do you mean set up web workers or something similar? @ViktorDanilov

Comment: I'm pretty sure web workers don't have access to the DOM.

Comment: Can't you just use a `for` loop? `for (var i = 0; i < 1e6; i++) { item.click(); }`. JS doesn't have threads and, as was pointed out, workers can't access the DOM.

Comment: I've completed the game and actually clicking it isn't the way to beat that level. The instructions even tell you not to.

Comment: Yeah I found it. Now in stuck in level 3.this is partly because I don't really understand the concept of sockets, frames, ddp, etc. Do you have any helpful hints?

Comment: @darryn.ten - yes, but changing the value to 1 000 000 didn't do anything. which is why i resorted to this, before trying 999 999 + 1 click

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The *'negative'* `while` loop should be slightly faster:

```
var i = 1000001;
while (--i) {
   item.click();
}
```

Choose one:
http://www.stoimen.com/blog/2012/01/24/javascript-performance-for-vs-while/

[Javascript Performance: While vs For Loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18640032/javascript-performance-while-vs-for-loops)

Comment: which is more efficient? a while loop or a for loop?

Comment: http://moduscreate.com/javascript-performance-tips-tricks/

Comment: https://jsperf.com/compare-while-loop-vs-for-loop/4

Comment: @max, good test. I prefer to use "for/while chached". We should store an array length into a variable to avoid array length evaluation on every loop iteration

Comment: I'm actually getting that the "reverse while" is 33% slower than the "basic while" on chrome. Too bad JSPerf is so broken that you can't see the results in other browsers.

Comment: @max, of course, among various browsers the results may differ

Answer (score 5):

JavaScript is single-threaded so keep it simple:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
    item.click();
}
```

EDIT: Looks like @romanperekhrest's answer may be slightly faster since it's using a decrementing while loop.

Comment: meh. looks like this crashed the site